# Laravel 5.3 auth routes redirecting to /

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I just upgraded to Laravel 5.3 (from 5.2) and now have issues with the auth routes.

I implemented the required methonds for the RegisterController and added `Auth::routes();` to `routes/web.php`. But when I access /register I always get redirected to `/`.

I have no idea why and don't see how I can figure out what's wrong.

**The middleware:**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Update: I found the reason: I was already signed in, therefore it always forwarded me. What I still don't know though, is were it's doing that?

Comment: Can you add the `middlewareGroups` property of your HTTP kernel ?

Comment: Just did that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the cause.

It's in the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
     return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Auth::routes() is just a helper class that helps you generate all the routes required for user authentication. To change the code you can browse below links:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

You probably have to check this function `$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');` to change the path or it has something to do with your Middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of that. The Controller is set up correctly, the middleware is the default one (see updated question).

Comment: Alright, no problem. Only thing I still can think of is setting the routes between a web middleware. Not sure what's causing your problems.

Comment: I found out the cause, but not how to fix it. See updated question.

Comment: I think it's in the `AuthController` and than here `protected $redirectTo = '/';` or same thing but in `LoginController`